# Coding-style for conditional operator in python

Tags: python, coding-style, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I want to get devs' opinions about next code examples. Which code is more readable? Which is better style?

Note: expression `int(a is not None) + 3*int(b is not None) + 5*int(a != b)` return unique code for all combinations values of listed conditions.

And sorry for my english. I am trying to make it better.

First:

```
if (a is not None) and (b is not None) and (a != b):
   exit()
elif (a is not None) and (b is not None) and (a = b):
   func1()
elif (a is not None) and (b is None):
   func2()
elif (a is None) and (b is not None):
   func3()
elif (a is None) and (b is None):
   func4
```

second:

```
code = int(a is not None) + 3*int(b is not None) + 5*int(a != b)
if code == 9:
   exit()
elif code == 4:
   func1()
elif code == 1:
   func2()
elif code == 3:
   func3()
elif code == 0:
   func4()
```

third:

```
code = int(a is not None) + 3*int(b is not None) + 5*int(a != b)    
switch = {9:exit, 4:func1, 1:func2, 3:func3, 0:func4}
switch[code]()
```

Comment: Anything that requires this convoluted a decision tree should probably be refactored instead.

Comment: This belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. But personally, I would build a simple truth-table based on a tuple of ``(a is None, b is None, a == b)`` as the key and the method to call as the value. It's like option 3, but much clearer.

Comment: Your line `elif (a is not None) and (b is not None) and (a = b):` should be `and (a == b)`

Answer (score 4):

I would do:

```
if a is None:
    if b is None: func4()
    else: func3()
else:
    if b is None: func2()
    elif a == b: func1()
    else: exit()
```

I'm definitely not a fan of the int switching. And, even more ideally, your structure for a and b would allow you to just check `not a` instead of `a is None`, which would be even cleaner.

In the off-chance that you do ever need to encode boolean flags into a number, I would also recommend that you use base 2 (1,2,4...) instead of the base system you're using (1,3,5..)--which might make sense if you were bounded by space (saving compressed data, eg [Chess bitboards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Board_representation_(chess)#Bitboard), or lots of fast network IO), but if you don't have a crazy requirement, remember:

> *"Premature optimization is the root of all evil." Donald Knuth*